# I can't make rails generate controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-1.9.3, rails-generate

I've ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.1

I'm try to generate a controller with this syntax:

```
$rails generate controller sessions new create failure
```

but respond me with this error:

> /Users/Uriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@omniauth/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load': /Users/Uriel/Documents/Uriel/omniauth/config/initializers/omniauth.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
>       from /Users/Uriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@omniauth/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in`block in load'
>       from /Users/Uriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@omniauth/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
>       from /Users/Uriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@omniauth/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in`new_constants_in'
>       from /Users/Uriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@omniauth/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
>       from /Users/Uriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@omniauth/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in`load'
>       from /Users/Uriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@omniauth/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
>       from /Users/Uriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@omniauth/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:554:in`each'
>       from /Users/Uriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@omniauth/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:554:in `block in <class:Engine>'
>       from /Users/Uriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@omniauth/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in`instance_exec'
>       from /Users/Uriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@omniauth/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
>       from /Users/Uriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@omniauth/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in`block in run_initializers'
>       from /Users/Uriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@omniauth/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
>       from /Users/Uriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@omniauth/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in`run_initializers'
>       from /Users/Uriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@omniauth/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:92:in `initialize!'
>       from /Users/Uriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@omniauth/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in`method_missing'
>       from /Users/Uriel/Documents/Uriel/omniauth/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /Users/Uriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@omniauth/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:78:in`require'
>       from /Users/Uriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@omniauth/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:78:in `require_environment!'
>       from /Users/Uriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@omniauth/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:22:in`'
>       from script/rails:6:in `require'
>       from script/rails:6:in`'

Thanks! :)

Comment: look in /Users/Uriel/Documents/Uriel/omniauth/config/initializers/omniauth.rb and add the missing `end`

Comment: As Brad said you need to fix missing `end`, can you post code from /Users/Uriel/Documents/Uriel/omniauth/config/initializers/omniauth.rb file?

Comment: Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, 631852046924694, 0a6624370a07e9f546c741dd2347b1bf
end